# Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElememtById'

Tags: getelementbyid

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="while.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="panel"><div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the script:

```
function init() {
  var panel=document.getElememtById("panel");
  var num=70;
  while (num > 10)  {
  panel.innerHTML="Countdown value: "+num+"<br>";
  num-=5;
}
}
window.onload=init;
```

Here's the resuts:

Google Console: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElememtById'

FireBug: document.getElememtById is not a function

IE: nothing

What's wrong with my script which I patched together from an example in a book?
Also, an inner div is created inside the #panel div.  What's that about?

Answers are so appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `getElementById`, not `getElememtById`. Looks like your issue is just a typo? :)

Comment: Sorry.  I do need new glasses.